# Strange error when i use pytest on a telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I have this Python bot, made with python-telegram-bot library:

```
logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
    level=logging.INFO
)

async def start(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    user = update.message.from_user
    await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="Hello,its xCoreBot!")

async def help(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="...command lists...")
```

I wrote these two tests:

```
def test_help(mocker: MockerFixture) -> None:
    # arrange
    chat=Chat(0, 'private')
    mock_update = Update(0, message=Message(0, text="/help", chat=chat, date=datetime.now()))
    mocker.patch.object(mock_update.message, 'reply_text', return_value=None)
    spy = mocker.spy(mock_update.message, 'reply_text')
    
    # act
    help(mock_update, None)

    # assert
    assert spy.call_count == 1
    assert spy.spy_return == None
```

and

```
def test_start(mocker: MockerFixture) -> None:
    # arrange
    chat=Chat(0, 'private')
    mock_update = Update(0, message=Message(0, text="/start", chat=chat, date=datetime.now()))
    mocker.patch.object(mock_update.message, 'reply_text', return_value=None)
    spy = mocker.spy(mock_update.message, 'reply_text')
    
    # act
    start(mock_update, None)

    # assert
    assert spy.call_count == 1
    assert spy.spy_return == None
```

When I call "pytest" I receive these errors:

```
=============================================== short test summary info ===============================================
FAILED tests/test_help.py::test_help - AttributeError: Attribute `reply_text` of class `Message` can't be deleted!
FAILED tests/test_start.py::test_start - AttributeError: Attribute `reply_text` of class `Message` can't be deleted!
================================================== 2 failed in 1.82s ==================================================
```

I don't know how to solve this error. Please help me.